# compare every row in two vectors with each other

Tags: r, vector, compare

I have a huge data base where I have to test for inconsistencies. One of the tests is to sum up some breakdown values and control if the total is equal to that. Summing up and comparing is not the problem. I used

`which(a+b+c+d != e)`, 
which gave back also values which are actually right. Surfing through stackoverflow showed that R has some problems with this kind of calculation. So I tried
`which(all.equal(sum(a,b,c,d),e)!=T)`,
which would give me the right result because of its testing of near equality,but it does not compare every row of sum(a,b,c,d) to every row of e, but the whole vectors.

Is there a function in R, which allows me to test every row in a way all.equal() does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may want to use `rowSums` with a column subset.  Using an example data frame `df`,

```
( df <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 2:5, z = c(3, 8, 2, 9)) )
#   x y z
# 1 1 2 3
# 2 2 3 8
# 3 3 4 2
# 4 4 5 9
rowSums(df[c("x", "y")]) == df[["z"]]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
which(rowSums(df[c("x", "y")]) == df[["z"]])
# [1] 1 4
```

But as it currently stands, your question is unclear.  Please update it to show exactly what you want.